# Spilled vinegar on iPhone earpiece

Tags: iphone, hardware, damage

I spilled a drop of balsamic vinegar on my iPhone 4S near the earpiece.

Now, call volume on the internal speaker is very low. How can I clean the earpiece out?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to open your iPhone, e.g. as [described on iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+iPhone+4+Display+Assembly+Replacement/11755/1). Then you can clean the affected area with a very gentle cleaning solution (but be aware to not use any solutions that may harm your hardware).

And for the next time: Don't place your cell phone near your salad. Balsamic vinegar is an aggresive solution which may severly damage pieces of your iPhone.

Comment: That last bit was unnecessary. I don't need to be told to be cautious.